# using static structs with array memebers

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I am trying to initialize and modify a static struct member variable with arrays and member because we need two sets of references.  The sturct looks like then creating a static member:

```
typedef struct ImgInfo
{
    int extent[6];
    double origin[3];
    double spacing[3];
};

class myClass {
public:
    static ImgInfo InternalImgInfo;
}
```

My issue is that I haven't been able to set the variables.  I've tried a few things, and none of them work at all.  How do you properly set a static struct with array members?

i.e. what is wrong with the following code:

```
static inline void GenerateImageInfo(int extent[6],double origin[3], double spacing[3], ImgInfo *rtn)
{
    for(int i = 0; i++; i < 6)
        rtn->extent[i] = extent[i];
    for(int i = 0; i++; i < 3){
        rtn->origin[i] = origin[i];
        rtn->spacing[i] = spacing[i];
    }
}
static inline ImgInfo GenerateImageInfo(int extent[6],double origin[3], double spacing[3])
{
    ImgInfo rtn;
    for(int i = 0; i++; i < 6)
        rtn.extent[i] = extent[i];
    for(int i = 0; i++; i < 3){
        rtn.origin[i] = origin[i];
        rtn.spacing[i] = spacing[i];
    }
    return rtn;
}
```

UPDATE:

somewhere in the myClass.cxx is:

```
ImgInfo myClass::InternalImgInfo = {{0,63,0,63,0,0},
        {0,0,0},{1,1,1}};
```

I'll mention how I am calling these functions.

```
int extent[6];
double spacing[3];
double origin[3];
// these arrays are filles with good values then: 
myClass::GenerateImageInfo(extent,spacing,origin,&myClass::InternalImgInfo);
```

OR

```
myClass::InternalImgInfomyClass = myClass::GenerateImageInfo(extent,spacing,origin);
```

Comment: There is nothing in your code that refers to the static struct member with `myClass::InternalImgInfo`.

Comment: You also have your for loop expressions the wrong way round. The test is in the middle and the ++ goes on the end.

Comment: Also instead of hard coded array lengths, use sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]).

Comment: @TheDark Wow.  I have been awake too long, thanks.  I can't believe I did that.  I have been switching languages too many times lately.

Comment: Well.. It was definitely just the loop expressions. Thanks for catching that @TheDark.

Comment: @Neil-McGill, is there some advantages to doing that.  These arrays must be of the size they are hard-coded, so those hardcoded values should always be the same.

Comment: When you have many places with hard coded sizes and come much later to modify the code it becomes a maintenance nightmare to hunt down all such places; if for example an array changes size. Best to use a static const value to represent the sizes, or a define or use the ARRAY_SIZE(x) ((sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])) trick. Hard coded anythings are generally not acceptable for maintainable code in industry.